# Icinga notifications are being marked as spam when sent to my mailbox

Tags: email, spf

I'm using gmail and my domain is foo.com

About half the notifications from my icinga server, icinga@foo.com go to my spam folder for me@gmail.com

```
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of icinga@foo.com does not designate <ip6> as permitted sender) client-ip=<ip6>;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=hardfail (google.com: domain of icinga@foo.com does not designate <ip6> as permitted sender) smtp.mail=icinga@foo.com
```

Is my current SPF record set up to allow my icinga server with the ip `<ip4>` and `<ip6>` to send email from the domain foo.com?

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
foo.com.               300     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:<ip4> ip6:<ip6> -all"
```

EDIT
Here are the results of two emails.  The ip address is the same between both of them.

```
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of icinga@foo.com does not designate 198.61.166.51 as permitted sender) client-ip=198.61.166.51;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=hardfail (google.com: domain of icinga@foo.com does not designate 198.61.166.51 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=icinga@foo.com

Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of icinga@foo.com designates 198.61.166.51 as permitted sender) client-ip=198.61.166.51;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of icinga@foo.com designates 198.61.166.51 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=icinga@foo.com
```

Comment: Google says **No** but since you have self-censored the IP addresses and your domain, we can't actually verify anything.  We don't mind you adding them to your question and they do make DNS questions *much* easier to answer.  Is there any difference between the half that go to your spam folder and the half that don't?  The `Received-SPF:` header might be a good place to check.

Comment: @Ladadadada I have updated my question with the `Received-SPF` header in a case where the emails pass and a case when the emails fail.  Please note the ip address is the same in the case that the emails pass and in the case that the emails fail.

Comment: I can't see any difference there apart from the SPF fail.  My next guess would be that your nameservers don't have the same data and one of them is serving up an SPF record that doesn't include that IP address (or no SPF record at all).  Your IPv4 address *is* listed on a couple of DNS Blacklists and doesn't have a PTR record but neither of these would cause a problem with Gmail.  The lack of PTR record *will* cause a problem when delivering to Gmail over IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

According to gmail:

Adding the sender "icinga@foo.com" to your Contacts list will prevent all but the most egregiously spam-like emails from getting tagged Spam.